# Improper assignment with rectangular empty matrix, how solve this error

Tags: matlab

I am trying to send binary data samples from basys 2, to matlab with COM4 cable via RS232 but MATLAB gives me "Improper assignment with rectangular empty matrix." error.
Here is my MATLAB CODE;

```
clc;clear all; close all; delete(instrfind);
%% SERIAL PORT COMMUNICATION (RS-232 Interface)
%% Parameters
s = serial('COM4'); % Modify COM4 according to your COM port
set(s,'BaudRate',115200); %DO NOT MODIFY (FIXED BAUDRATE)
set(s,'InputBufferSize',2^10);  % 1024 byte (you don't have to modify)
set(s,'OutputBufferSize',2^10); % 1024 byte (you don't have to modify)
get(s) % Properties of your serial port

%index parameters
k=1;
nofElem=21; %Number of receive samples (21 for test samples) MODIFY FOR DATA samples
decdata=zeros(1,nofElem); % integer data

%% Read From Serial Port
fopen(s);
while (1)  
decdata(k) = fread(s,1);
k=k+1;
if k == nofElem 
    break; % break the inf loop
end
end
fclose(s);
plot(decdata)
```

Comment: What line gives that error?

Comment: decdata(k) = fread(s,1)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to solve error 'Improper assignment with rectangular empty matrix'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274032/how-to-solve-error-improper-assignment-with-rectangular-empty-matrix)

Comment: I believe this error is because `fread` is for reading a binary file. you may be looking for `fscanf`. Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233394/how-to-read-serial-data-correctly-through-matlab

Comment: I am sending binary numbers serially, fscanf didn't work.

Comment: @FatihALTINDİŞ You are rigth, there is a `fread` for your purpose. My guess is then that there is nothing being received in the serial port, thus `fread` gives an empty result

Comment: Try setting `fread(s,1)` to a test variable first (i.e. `test = fread(s,1)`) and then debug to see what the value is *before* you try and assign it to `decdata(k)`

Comment: If this answer helped, please consider accepting it as valid, so people will know that this is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your code to the following.
I just added a check to see if there is something read from the serial port, and to see the cause of why nothing has been read.

```
fopen(s);

while (k<nofElem)
   tic
   aux=fread(s,1);
   t=toc;
   if(isempty(aux))
       if t>=get(s,'Timeout')
          error('Timeout. Waited for too long')
       else
          error('Nothing read from serial port and I dont know why');
       end
   end
   decdata(k) = aux;
   k=k+1;

end
```

Comment: Surely `while k ~= nofElem`?

Comment: @Dan Yeah I think is better, but this still works, and messes less with the OP code I think.

Comment: I would probably use `k < nofElem`. If somehow (magically) `k` becomes larger than `nofElem`, this would stop the loop - `k ~= nofElem` wouldn't. Or is there any reason against using `<`?

Comment: @hbaderts I dont know if there is! I am surely using `<` ;)